# How can I pass multiple values for a single parameter into the API URL in JavaScript using express?

Tags: javascript, express

I have to pass:

```
{health:['vegetarian','vegan'], diet:['high-protein','low-fat']}
```

into the API URL:

```
http://......?health=vegetarian&health=vegan&diet=high-protein&diet=low-fat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a JSON format and parse the array once on the server-side since the values of `req.query` are strings:

`?health=["foo","bar"]&diet=["high-protein","low-fat"]`

```
const { health, diet } = req.query;

try {
    const healthArr = JSON.parse(health);
    const dietArr = JSON.parse(diet);
} catch (err) {
    // handle err
}
```